# Is there a way to modify the kerning/leading/tracking of a UIFont?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uifont, typography

Here is how I define fonts on my UILabels:

```
label.text = "Hello"
label.font = CustomFont.font(size: 16) // Resolves to `UIFont(name: "CustomFont", size: 16)`
```

I'd like to apply a specific kerning/leading/tracking for `CustomFont`, depending on text size. I can do this by using attributed strings but this implies massive code changes, breaking tests, and more cognitive load for next development (i.e.: remember to always use attributed strings for all labels).

Is there a way to modify kerning/leading/tracking at the UIFont level? I've heard about [UIFontDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontdescriptor) but I'm unsure which key/values I should be using, or whether it would work at all.